# attach compressed file to PDF

Tags: pdf, adobe, digital-signature, pdfbox

using PDF box I can attach document to PDF.

```
PDComplexFileSpecification fs = new PDComplexFileSpecification();
fs.setFile( "Test.txt" );
InputStream is = ...;
PDEmbeddedFile ef = new PDEmbeddedFile(doc, is );
//set some of the attributes of the embedded file
ef.setSubtype( "test/plain" );
ef.setSize( data.length );
ef.setCreationDate( new GregorianCalendar() );
fs.setEmbeddedFile( ef );
Map efMap = new HashMap();
efMap.put( "My first attachment", fs );
efTree.setNames( efMap );
PDDocumentNameDictionary names = new PDDocumentNameDictionary( doc.getDocumentCatalog() );
names.setEmbeddedFiles( efTree );
doc.getDocumentCatalog().setNames( names );
```

but how to compress that file? I know that PDStream have method addCompression(). should I use that?

I found solution:

```
            PDEmbeddedFile embeddedFile = new PDEmbeddedFile(doc, attachedFileInputStream );  
            List<COSName> list = new ArrayList<COSName>(); 
            COSName filter = COSName.LZW_DECODE;

            list.add(filter);
            embeddedFile.setFilters(list);
            embeddedFile.setFileFilters(null);
            embeddedFile.addCompression();
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found solution:

```
        PDEmbeddedFile embeddedFile = new PDEmbeddedFile(doc, attachedFileInputStream );
        embeddedFile.addCompression();
        List<COSName> list = new ArrayList<COSName>();
        list.add(COSName.FLATE_DECODE);
        embeddedFile.setFilters(list);
```